# Why are my div elements not aligned vertically?

Tags: html, css

```css
/* Feuille de style (économiseur d'écran) CSS version 1.0 créée le 30.05.2016
*/

/* Page entière (utilisé pour avoir une couverture globale en couleur) */
body {
 background-color:#005580;  /*night mode*/
 background-color:black;  /*screensaver mode*/
}

/* Affichage de date (en haut) */
#date{
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size: 130%;
 font-weight: 800;
 text-align: left;
 position: fixed;
 top: 5px;
 left: 20px;
 color:black;  /* night mode*/
 color:blue;   /* day mode*/
 color:white;  /* screensaver mode*/
}
#clearfix{display:block} 
/* Affichage d'heure (en haut) */
#time{
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size: 130%;
 font-weight: 800;
 text-align: left;
 position: fixed;
 top: 5px;
 left: 300px;
 color:black;  /* night mode*/
 color:blue;   /* day mode*/
 color:white;  /* screensaver mode*/
}

/* Affichage du lever et de coucher de soleil */
#tag_sunrise_sunset{
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size: 90%;
 text-align: left;
 position: fixed;
 top: 55px;
 left: 140px;
 color:black;
}

/* Affichage des données météorologiques additionnelles */
#tag_additional_weather_information{
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 position: fixed;
 top: 70px;
 left: 450px;
 width:250px;
 color:black;
}

/* Affichage des alertes météorologiques */
#tag_meteo_alert{
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 position: fixed;
 top: 15px;
 left: 450px;
 width:250px;
 color:red;
}

/* Affichage de la température */
#tag_temperature{
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size: 130%;
 font-weight: 800;
 text-align: left;
 position: fixed;
 top: 1px;
 left: 420px;
 color:black;  /* night mode*/
 color:blue;   /* day mode*/
 color:white;  /* screensaver mode*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- 
 Page d'économiseur d'écran, créée le 30.07.2016 
 modifiée le 02.09.2016 
 modifiée le 22.10.2016 (no cache) 
 modifiée le 23.10.2016 (inclusion de la date et de l'heure)
-->
<html>
<head>
 <title>Domoos | Screen saver screen</title>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
 <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle_saver.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/date_time.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/screensaver.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
 <div style="position:absolute" id="randomPlacement">
  <p><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/pictures/texte_sortie_veille.png" alt ="" style="width:60px;height:60px;"></a></p>
 </div>
 <div id="date"></div>
 <div id="time"></div>
 <div id="tag_temperature">
  <p>16&deg;C</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the following html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Domoos | Screen saver screen</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle_saver.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/date_time.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/screensaver.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <div style="position:absolute" id="randomPlacement">
        <p><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/pictures/texte_sortie_veille.png" alt ="" style="width:60px;height:60px;"></a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="date"></div>
    <div id="time"></div>
    <div id="tag_temperature">
        <p>16&deg;C</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the following linked CSS file (extract of the file named 'mystyle_saver.css') :

```
 /* Page entière (utilisé pour avoir une couverture globale en couleur) */
body {
    background-color:black;  /*screensaver mode*/
}

/* Affichage de date (en haut) */
#date{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 20px;
    color:white;        /* screensaver mode*/
}

/* Affichage d'heure (en haut) */
#time{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 300px;
    color:white;        /* screensaver mode*/
}
/* Affichage de la température */
#tag_temperature{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    top: 1px;
    left: 420px;
    color:black;        /* night mode*/
    color:blue;         /* day mode*/
    color:white;        /* screensaver mode*/
}
```

Now for the problem I am facing: All my div tags (date, time and tag_temperature) have the same properties : font-family, size, weight, ... and top value, however the temperature is not well aligned with the rest. The screenshot below will better illustrate this :

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Many thanks for your support.

Comment: add jsfiddle so we can help you

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: because all of the has fixed position. try to put a <div class="clearfix"></div> between your divs with fix position and give .clearfix{display:block}

Comment: and line-height, learn what it does

Comment: `clearfix` makes no difference on _fixed position_, it _fixes_ the _float_ values, right? Either way. A working sample would be better, you can use SO snippets (its the document icon with the `<>` in it) to put your code in-page and let people try it, we can help you better if you do.

Comment: you can always add your code in https://jsfiddle.net/  it gives a good environment for web developers

Comment: @mkafiyan SO snippets are very good and easily available _within_ this site, helping the answer stand the test of time. If you are advising people to use one, tell them to use SO snippets where available for convenience of the users of this site.

Comment: @somethinghere yes you right.

Comment: @somethinghere, I followed your advice and I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your temperature is in a `<p>` element which has a default top and bottom margin.

Add this to your CSS to remove it:

```
p {margin: 0;}
```

Note that this may have other undesirable side-effects on your text.

Also, your `top` pixel alignments are not the same on your date, time and temp.

JS fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/sxz3dfux/

Comment: Excellent, that is absolutely what I was looking for. I didn't pay attention to the <p> tag. Thanks a lot. Best wishes.

Comment: My suggestion for you (@Laurent) is to use css reset to reset all of those default style which will make designing web page much easier. Check this out [cssreset](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) and include all of the code inside your css file.

Comment: @THCoder , thanks for the suggestion and the hint. I really appreciate